# Solving $\cos^2(a)+\cos(a) = \sin^2(a)$ by using a vector product

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

$$\cos^2(a)+\cos(a) = \sin^2(a)$$

I'm required to solve it using vectors. Let me show my attempt.

We know that

$$u\cdot v=|u||v| \iff v=ku$$

Recall that

$$ u=(1,1,1)\implies |u|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}=\sqrt 3$$

$$v=[\cos^2(a), \cos(a), \sin^2(a)]$$

I couldn't define $v$. That's why I couldn't proceed further.

Regards

Comment: Can you give some more detail on the problem statement? I am not really sure what you are looking for

Comment: Are you forced to use vectors?

Comment: @gimusi Yes, lol.

Comment: @Dashi I'm trying to solve it by vector product.

Comment: @Busi, you mean trying to solve for a?

Comment: @Busi Sorry but at the moment I can't see a convenient way to proceed by vectors. There are others strategies more effective. If you are interested I can post them. Using vectors to solve trigonometric equations is not a trick often used so is very important that you can approach the problem also by classical methods.

Comment: @gimusi I'm really interested. Please show the more effective ways, they have too importance for me.

Comment: How does one proceed from $\cos^2 a+\cos a=\sin^2 a \iff ( 1,1,1) \cdot \left(\cos^2 a,\cos a,-\sin^2 a\right )  =0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as
$$\cos^2(a) - \sin^2(a) = -\cos(a)$$
which is equivalent to the vector equation
$$\left<\cos(a), \sin(a)\right> \cdot \left<\cos(a),-\sin(a) \right> = -\cos(a)$$
Now write $\textbf{u}=\left<\cos(a), \sin(a)\right>$ and $\textbf{v}=\left<\cos(a), -\sin(a)\right>$.  We observe that both **u** and **v** are unit vectors, and the angle between them is $2a$.  Therefore from $$\textbf{u}\cdot \textbf{v} = |\textbf{u}||\textbf{v}|\cos(\theta)$$
(where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors) we find that the equation is equivalent to
$$\cos(2a) = -\cos(a)$$

(Of course, we could have gotten to this same conclusion much simpler by just using the double-angle identity $\cos(2a) = \cos^2(a) - \sin^2(a)$, but OP  wanted something that explicitly uses vectors, so we took the long way around.)

The most straightforward way to interpret this latter equation is as follows:  we are seeking a point on the unit circle, located by an angle $a$, with the property that doubling $a$ either reflects the point across the $y$-axis or across the origin.  By inspection one can see that $a = \frac{\pi}{3}$ is the only angle in the first quadrant with that property, $a = \frac{5\pi}{3}$ is the only angle in the fourth quadrant with that property, and in addition $a=\pi$ has that property; it's not too hard to reason your way to the conclusion that the angle can't be anywhere else.

I don't see any "purely vectorial" way to solve $\cos(2a) = -\cos(a)$, but then again I'm not completely sure what "using vectors" means in the OP's context.

Comment: Unclear how you actually obtained $\cos(2a) = -\cos(a)$. Could you explain?

Comment: @Busi As I said, **u** and **v** are both unit vectors, and the angle between them is $\theta=2a$, so their dot product is $\cos(2a)$.  On the other hand the equation we are trying to solve says that the dot product is $-\cos(a)$.  So those must be equal.

Comment: Yes, but what does unit vector mean? And how did you find out the angle between them?

Comment: I'm starting to think you don't understand what vectors are.

Comment: I've gotten it. However, did we only obtain one solution from $\cos(2a) = -\cos(a)$? What I found is $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$. There should be more solutions than I found

Comment: I explicitly named 3 solutions in my answer.  Please try to read more closely.

Answer (score 0):

With vectors, one could proceed as follows:

$$\cos^2 a+\cos a=\sin^2 a \iff ( 1,1,1) \cdot \left(\cos^2 a,\cos a,-\sin^2 a\right )  =0$$

The convenient values of $a$ are in the gimusi's answer and the math community is satisfied :) , but I feel you want to see how to continue with $||v||:$

$$||v||=\sqrt{\cos^4 a+\cos^2 a+\sin^4 a}=\sqrt{2\cos^4 a-\cos^2 a+1}.$$

But I do not see how this can help you to continue.

Comment: How does one find solution from $\cos^2 a+\cos a=\sin^2 a \iff ( 1,1,1) \cdot \left(\cos^2 a,\cos a,-\sin^2 a\right )  =0$? and I was looking for $|v|$ instead.

Comment: Solution was given by gimusi. Unfortunately, he deleted it. The equation $a\cos^a+\cos a-1=0$ can be rewritten as $(2\cos a -1)(\cos a+1)=0.$ Solve $\cos a = 1/2$ and $\cos a =-1.$